# Angular CLI: How to use window, document or location in environment.ts

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Does anyone knows how to use window, document or location in an environment.ts file? I'm getting an error when compiling

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling
function 'window', function calls are not supported. Consider
replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported
function, resolving symbol environment in ...
```

The angular cli version I'm using is 1.0.0-beta.26

Answer (score 0):

**environment.ts** this file will be using in nodejs server. in node there is no window, document, location global variables. you cannot using these variables node. if you wanna using global variable, just attach into `global` object.

https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global

> In browsers, the top-level scope is the global scope. That means that
>   in browsers if you're in the global scope `var something` will define a
>   global variable. In Node.js this is different. The top-level scope is
>   not the global scope; `var something` inside an Node.js module will be
>   local to that module.